# How to set command argument in vscode task.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I would like to automate extension setting with some arguments on task runner in VSCode.
How can I set arguments:

- string argument
- menu selection

I tried something like :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [         
          {
            "label": "spark setting",
            "command": "${command:hdinsight.linkCluster}",
          },
}
```

I tried applying "args" section :

```
 {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [         
          {
            "label": "spark setting",
            "command": "${command:hdinsight.linkCluster}",
            "args": ["Generic Livy Endpoint", "htttp://*****"]
          },
}
```

But it seems doesn't work to automate.

The extension command 'linkCluster' requires both menu selection and string argument which is URI.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to specify the args if you use the `command` variables directly in the task definition, but **inputs** (despite the name) allow commands with arguments:

```
    tasks": [
        {
            "label": "mytask",
            "command": "${input:first}",
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
          "id": "first",
          "type": "command",
          "command": "hdinsight.linkCluster",
          "args": ["Generic Livy Endpoint", "htttp://*****"]
       ]
```